# Create a bogus state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How do you create a fake state, same as the current one? That's gonna give us two identical in the history, so when you click back you stay in the same one.

I tried this `$state.go($state.current)`, no luck.

Backstory: I have a cart that needs to be shown/overlayed above all other unrelated views that have their own paths (states). And when you go back on the browser, just the cart needs to close, not the state we are at. Get it? I need bogus double state for that.

Right now, on click back, I'm canceling the state transition if the cart is open, but, that's not possible if you just landed at the page. You cannot prevent transitioning back if there's only one state in the current site history.

Comment: why would you need something like that?

Comment: If the user clicks back a second time, should they go back? Or are you trying to lock them into a state forever/disable the back button?

Comment: It's cool how you first question my reasoning :}

Answer (score 0):

Is the History API an option for you?

If so you could set the handler for the 'onEnter' event and inject the artificial state there.

Comment: Don't you think $state.go() is an abstraction for History API?

Comment: Kind of, at the end it will use Angulars $browser.url() and there the history is only updated if the new URL is different from the current one.